# Filter through a table to search through foreign key data

Tags: wpf, listview, binding, filter

the title of this question may sound confusing so I shall try to explain myself the best way I can.

I'm creating an application that has many tables with many `foreign key` constraints. For example, in my case I have a student. Each student table has a `foreign key` relation with a parental details table and medical details table.

To make my application easy to use, I have implemented a series of different `filters` to help a user search through large amounts of data.

I have one `listview` to display the student records, and same with the parental and medical details. However, what I want to do is to search through the student records based on a set of criteria from the parental details. For example, search for a parental name. Eg; is a student has a parent called Bob, the `listview` will `filter` the students who's parent is called Bob.

This is what I've tried;

```
   //Constructor;
   StudentList = new ObservableCollection<StudentViewModel>(GetStudents());

   CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(StudentList).Filter = new Predicate<object>(MainFilter);

   //Properties
   private string contactNameSearch;
   public string ContactNameSearch
   {
       get { return contactNameSearch; }
       set
       {
           contactNameSearch = value;
           CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(StudentList).Refresh();
           OnPropertyChanged("ContactNameSearch");
       }
   }

   private bool FilterContactNameSearch(object obj)
   {
       StudentContactViewModel item = obj as StudentContactViewModel;
       if (item == null) return false;
       if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ContactNameSearch)) return true;

       if (ContactNameSearch.Trim().Length == 0) return true;

       if (item.Name1.ToLower().Contains(ContactNameSearch.ToLower())) return true;
       return false;
   }

   public bool MainFilter(object o)
   {
       return FilterContactNameSearch(o); // &... and more filters
   }

   //Xaml
   <TextBox Height="23" Name="txtContactName" Width="100" 
                    Text="{Binding ContactNameSearch, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

The code snippet above it what I have implemented for my other `filter`, which all of them work fine. However, when I `bind` this `property` to the `textbox` within my application, all of a sudden the data which populates the `listview` vanishes. [This link here shows the before and after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvt9A.jpg)

If I put a `breakpoint` around the *ContactNameSearch* `property`, I also get a "No Window Source" dialog appear.

I have put together a small sample which can be found [by click here](https://gist.github.com/gregorybmclub/2dce50cb5272def4e2a9)

Therefore, my question is; Am I implementing this correctly and if not, is there an alternative way of doing it?

Comment: reading the code that you have shown in the sample, did you try to change with an "||" instead of an "&" here?  return FilterSchoolSearch(o) & FilterContactNameSearch(o) & FilterNameSearch(o) & FilterFormSearch(o) & FilterIDSearch(o)
                & FilterEnrollment(o) & FilterNameSearch(o);  Because if you put an "&", if one of those filters returns false, all the result of MainFilter will be false...

Comment: @MauroBilotti Thanks for your reply. I shall change it to see if that works.

Comment: You are welcome! Tell me if it solves your problem...

Comment: Should I change them all to `|` rather then &?

Comment: I think so... if you have three filters and one of those is false, all will be false and the listview will not show any result. I think that the problem is the way that you are applying the logic of the filters, and that's the reason why the lisview results empty.

Comment: I think that is easier by using a button which fires an event and then bind the ListView to the filtered ObservableCollection.

Comment: @MauroBilotti I used `||` and the data populates the `listview`; previously before making the change it didn't. However, it doesn't filter the list of items dependent on the criteria.

Answer (score 1):

When provide users with filtering functionality in my applications, I tend to use two collections. One has the whole unfiltered collection and once filled, that remains unchanged. The other is to only contain items from the first collection that match the given filter condition(s). This second collection is the one that is data bound to the `ItemsControl.ItemsSource` property in the UI.

```
public ObservableCollection<YourDataType> DataTypes
{
    get { return dataTypes; }
    set
    {
        if (dataTypes != value) 
        {
            dataTypes = value; 
            NotifyPropertyChanged("DataTypes");
            FilterDataTypes();
        }
    }
}

public ObservableCollection<YourDataType> FilteredDataTypes // Data bind this one
{
    get { return filteredDataTypes ?? (filteredDataTypes = DataTypes); }
    private set { filteredDataTypes = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("FilteredDataTypes"); }
}
```

Now, your `FilterDataTypes` method basically needs to filter the `DataTypes` collection by whatever means you see fit and populate the `FilteredDataTypes` collection. This example uses a `string` input that is data bound to a filter box in the UI and the actual filter condition is in the `CheckFields` method.

```
private void FilterDataTypes()
{
    filteredDataTypes = new ObservableCollection<YourDataType>();
    string filterText = FilterText.Trim().ToLower();
    if (filterText == string.Empty)
    {
        foreach (YourDataType dataType in DataTypes)
        {
            FilteredDataTypes.Add(dataType);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (YourDataType dataType in DataTypes.Where(m => CheckFields(m)))
        {
            FilteredDataTypes.Add(dataType);
        }
    }
    NotifyPropertyChanged("FilteredDataTypes");
}

private bool CheckFields(YourDataType dataType)
{
    string filterText = FilterText.Trim().ToLower();
    return filterText == string.Empty ? true : 
        dataType.Parent.Name.ToLower().Contains(filterText);
}

public string FilterText
{
    get { return filterText; }
    set
    {
        if (filterText != value)
        {
            filterText = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("FilterText");
            FilterDataTypes(); // <-- Filters collection when value is changed
        }
    }
}
```

Now this simple example only has one filter input, but you can add as many as you want using other methods like the `CheckFields` method, but based on the values of other data bound properties:

```
private void FilterDataTypes()
{
    filteredDataTypes = new ObservableCollection<YourDataType>();
    string filterText = FilterText.Trim().ToLower();
    if (filterText == string.Empty)
    {
        foreach (YourDataType dataType in DataTypes)
        {
            FilteredDataTypes.Add(dataType);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (YourDataType dataType in 
            DataTypes.Where(m => CheckFields(m) | CheckOptions(m)))
        {
            FilteredDataTypes.Add(dataType);
        }
    }
    NotifyPropertyChanged("FilteredDataTypes", "DataTypesCount");
}

public YourDataType SelectedItem // <-- Data bind to ItemsControl.SelectedItem
{
    get { return selectedItem; }
    set
    {
        if (selectedItem != value)
        {
            selectedItem = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
            FilterDataTypes();
        }
    }
}

private bool CheckOptions(YourDataType dataType) // <-- And use to filter collection
{
    string filterText = SelectedItem.Name.Trim().ToLower();
    return filterText == string.Empty ? true : 
        dataType.Doctor.Name.ToLower().Contains(filterText);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am going through the code you provided and I have a few errors. Firstly, you refer to "DataTypesCount" what is this property? Also, I am unable to call "AddRange(StudentList)" as theres no extension.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to remove the call to `DataTypesCount`... you can ignore that. As for the `AddRange` method, either add an extension method to the `ObservableCollection<T>` class that adds multiple items, or just add them using the `Add` method in a loop instead.

Comment: I understand how you achieve this, just trying to incorporate this into my application. So for every new item you want to filter you add it to the `FilterDataTypes()` method, is that correct? I Also get the following error; Error  `Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<StudentViewModel>' to 'StudentViewModel'`

Comment: Dude... `FilterDataTypes` is a method, so you cannot add items to it and how am I supposed to know where you get that error from? To be honest with you, I feel that I already spent a long time answering your question and in *far* more detail than most answers. I'm really hoping that you can work the rest out for your self because I don't have the time to teach you all the basics of programming, such as `foreach` loops and casting errors (your last error). If you really can't tell the difference between `IEnumerable<StudentViewModel>` and `StudentViewModel`, then we're just wasting time here.

Comment: Just read through my answer again... I feel that it's quite clear.

Comment: I was simply just saying that I understood what you provided for me which I thoroughly appreciate your time and effort. What I meant by my previous comment was  that within the `else FilteredDataTypes.Add(StudentList.Where(m => CheckFields(m) | CheckOptions(m)));` this is where you place more filters, am I not mistaken? (just needed some clarity) And I am aware of the difference between them.